# ggplot2 geom_bar color bars by one column and outline by another column

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe has the following columns:

1. Proportion, which is the y axis.
2. Category, which is the x axis and have 7 categories
3. Group1, which is binary
4. Group2, which has 4 groups, multiple categories could belong to a same group.

I wish to color the bars by Group2 (so fill = Group2), but I couldn't figure out how to make bars outlined or not based on Group1 as well. My current code is

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Category,y=Proportion, fill = Group1, group = Group2)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
    xlab("") + 
    ylab("Proportion") + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position="top") + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

I am new to R visualization, so it would be really nice if someone could tell me how to outline the bars based on the grouping.

Here's how the dataframe should look like:

```
> df
   Category Proportion Group1 Group2
1         1          45      a      A
2         2          40      a      A
3         3          49      a      A
4         4          47      a      A
5         5          43      a      A
6         1          32      a      B
7         2          37      a      B
8         3          45      a      B
9         4          47      a      B
10        5          50      a      B
11        6          49      b      A
12        7          34      b      A
13        8          31      b      A
14        6          36      b      B
15        7          46      b      B
16        8          39      b      B
17        9          42      c      A
18        9          31      c      B
19       10          31      d      A
20       10          44      d      B
```

Here's the current output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Mwn.png)

I want the bars on left of each group to be outlined (white filling and the edge be the same color as the group)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I do want the bars in each group to be side by side, not stacked.

Comment: What color do you want to make the outlines? I'm not clear what your desired output us here. Just like solid black? You can set `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), color="black")` It's hard to help when we have no idea what the plot currently looks like. A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, Please see the update for a toy example and my current output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

Set fill to `Group2` then color to `Group1`. You can override the legend if you want a particular color or fill. I added `factor` around `Category` to get the x axis to make more sense, although I suspect your actual `Category` is already a factor.

Note your data column is `Proportions`, although your code is `Proportion`.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=factor(Category),y=Proportions, fill = Group2, color = Group1)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values =c(A = "white", B = "gray")) +
    xlab("") + ylab("Proportion") + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position="top") + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                               list(color = "gray")),
           color = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                               list(fill = "gray")))
```

[image]

If you're dead set on the fill matching the color, it gets more complicated, but you can use `interaction(Group2,Group1)` as the fill. Then you have to manually determine the colors for the interactions.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(Category),y=Proportions, fill = interaction(Group2,Group1), color = Group1)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(c(rep("white",4),"cornflowerblue","forestgreen","firebrick3","goldenrod"),
                                        sort(unique(as.character(interaction(df$Group2,df$Group1))))),
                      breaks = c("A.a","B.a"),
                      labels = c("A","B")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c("cornflowerblue","forestgreen","firebrick3","goldenrod"),
                                         sort(unique(as.character(df$Group1))))) +
    labs(x = "", y = "Proportion") + 
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position="top") + 
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                               list(color = "gray",
                                    fill = c("white","darkgray"))),
           color = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                               list(fill = c("white"))))
```

[image]

To understand what's going on here, consider this:

```
interaction(df$Group2,df$Group1)
[1] A.a A.a A.a A.a A.a B.a B.a B.a B.a B.a A.b A.b A.b B.b B.b B.b A.c B.c A.d B.d
Levels: A.a B.a A.b B.b A.c B.c A.d B.d
```

If we sort and unique this, we get the following:

```
sort(unique(as.character(interaction(df$Group2,df$Group1))))
[1] "A.a" "A.b" "A.c" "A.d" "B.a" "B.b" "B.c" "B.d"
```

We want the first 4 to be white, so we can use `rep`, and then manually define the others.

```
c(rep("white",4),"cornflowerblue","forestgreen","firebrick3","goldenrod")
[1] "white"          "white"          "white"          "white"          "cornflowerblue" "forestgreen"    "firebrick3"     "goldenrod"
```

From here we can use `setNames` to apply the fills to the values:

```
setNames(c(rep("white",4),"cornflowerblue","forestgreen","firebrick3","goldenrod"),
                                         sort(unique(as.character(interaction(df$Group2,df$Group1)))))
             A.a              A.b              A.c              A.d              B.a              B.b              B.c              B.d 
         "white"          "white"          "white"          "white" "cornflowerblue"    "forestgreen"     "firebrick3"      "goldenrod"
```

Repeat the process for the colors.

We don't necessarily want to see all of the `interaction()`'s in the legend. So we can limit them with the `breaks =`  argument. We can rename `A.a` and `B.a` to just `A` and `B` with `labels =`.

Comment: This looks awesome! Thanks!